# Offline Capabilities for Salesforce 1

Tags: offline

We have developed an application with a number of custom objects and visualforce pages. We will use Salesforce 1 on the road, and I was wondering what the standard offline capabilities of Salesforce are?

When I meet with a client, is it possible to download their related data to my device first, and if yes, how can I do that?

Tia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce1 offline capabilities are mostly read-only.
You can put in cache the last consulted elements (records and dashboards) anytime you want directly on your smartphone. You can also ask the application to put in cache these elements automatically each time you lose your connection.

Last : you can manage global settings of your Salesforce1 users in the habitual backoffice.

Salesforce help is useful : https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_sf1_offline.htm&language=en_US